# Django query count only on a specific column

Tags: sql, django, count, django-queryset

Why does Django's `count()` result in a SQL query like

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
```

and is there a way to just count on a single column?

For instance, having a model with the following rows:
- id
- first_name
- last_name
Instead of having the count run on `*` which is similar to `SELECT COUNT(id, first_name, last_name)` I would like to only run

```sql
SELECT COUNT(id)
```

Or best to do `SELECT COUNT(1)`. I want to do this because I once heard that this would be faster for huge tables.

NOTE: If it's faster or not is not the question, it's how to do the query with Django. So please don't mark it as duplicated with [Count(*) vs Count(1) - SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1-sql-server)

Comment: what do you mean "count on a single row"? What exactly do you want to count? Please be specific.

Comment: @dirkgroten I updated the question. Hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1-sql-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count(\*) vs Count(1) - SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1-sql-server)

Comment: Note also that if you do `COUNT(id)` on column that may contain NULL values, you will receive a different result, as row with null values will not be counted. Use Django's `aggregate` if you actually want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the purpose is to count rows that do not have a NULL value in column `x`, you should use Django's `aggregate`:

```
MyModel.objects.aggregate(Count('x'))
```

But if your purpose is to speed up your query, than this is pointless as `SELECT COUNT(*)` or `SELECT COUNT(x)` have the exact same speed as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1-sql-server).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Entry.objects.values_list('field_name', flat=True).count()
```